# Custom membership in mvc entity framework 6

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am using Entity Framework 6 in my project and applying custom membership for the project. Custom membership is located in different project of a same solution. I referenced the main project and the database but i am still getting the error on dbcontext....

The type 'System.Data.Entity.DbContext' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.    E:\Project\ECommerce\ECommerce\Authentication\Authentication.cs 180 13  Authentication

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In adition to the main project and database references, you have to add the reference to the Entity Framework [Nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EntityFramework) to the project with the custom membership authentication stuff.

Comment: thank you for your response...I have done a silly mistake.